# How does createElement() work with innerHTML?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code that pretty much creates a div element and whatever is inside and puts it into

```
function create(htmlStr) {
    var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(), temp = document.createElement('div');
    temp.innerHTML = htmlStr;
    while (temp.firstChild) {
        frag.appendChild(temp.firstChild);
    }
    return frag;
}

var fragment = create('<div id="test">HELLO</div>');
document.body.insertBefore(fragment, document.body.childNodes[0]);
```

1. I am, however, confused as to why do we create another 
   `div` `temp = document.createElement('div');`
   If we are already passing `<div id="test">HELLO</div>` to `create()` function. Seems to me that would create a div within a div (but it doesn't). Or does that just get extracted with `temp.firtChild`?
2. What does `temp.innerHTML = htmlStr;` do since `temp` is a `div`?

Comment: Your `while` looks like never ending.

Comment: @techfoobar - when `appendChild()` is called, the element that was a child of `temp` is *removed* from `temp` and becomes a child of `frag`.

Comment: @gilly3 - Ah.. ok. That for some reason din cross my mind. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your 1st question, it basically creates a parent div to contain the `htmlStr`, which happens to be `<div id="test">HELLO</div>`. So basically, this line of code by itself simply generates a div, but this `temp` div is then used to contain the `htmlStr` as a child. But you are right; the `temp` div is simply extracted later; it's pretty much useless. I don't know why that's there if there is no other code to consider.

As for question 2, all it does is make the `htmlStr` a child of the created div. In effect, this code makes `temp.innerHTML == htmlStr == temp.firstChild`. It's kinda redundant.

Basically, your code makes the following HTML:

```
<div>
    <div id="test">HELLO</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That code does create a wrapping div with `createElement`, and assigns the `htmlStr` as its contents. But then it proceeds to move the contents out of that div, one child at a time, into `frag`, until the div is empty again. The function returns just `frag`, leaving an empty div behind. It's never added to the DOM, and will be garbage-collected later.

Basically it's a way to let the browser parse (and possibly fix) the HTML string for you, and make it into a valid DOM subtree.